# adding 2 cells when joining

Tags: r, join, dataset

I want to join 2 datasets, but there are more values in the same cell. My dataset `bookings` looks like this:

```
     ID   numofRooms                   roomIDs
1160545            1                   1202544
1160546            2           1202547|1202563
1160547            2           1202562|1202564
1160548            1                   1202565
1160549            1                   1202566
1160550            3   1203751|1203752|1203753
```

The dataset `rooms` has the following columns:

```
     ID   numofBeds
1202544          10
1202547           2
1202563           3
1202562           5
1202564           4
1202565           4
1202566           7
1203751           1
1203752           2
1203753           3
```

So i want to add `numofBeds` for the same booking. my expected outcome is:

```
     ID   numofRooms                   roomIDs   numofBeds
1160545            1                   1202544          10
1160546            2           1202547|1202563           5
1160547            2           1202562|1202564           9
1160548            1                   1202565           4
1160549            1                   1202566           7
1160550            3   1203751|1203752|1203753           6
```

I hope you might know a way to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

One option is `tidyverse`.  Split the 'roomIDs' column in the first dataset ('bookings') into 'long' format, then `left_join` with 'rooms', after grouping by 'ID', 'numofRooms', `summarise` the 'roomIDs' by `paste`ing the elements together while calculate the 'numofbeds' as the `sum` of the 'numofbeds'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)   
bookings %>%
  separate_rows(roomIDs, convert = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(rooms, by = c(roomIDs = 'ID')) %>% 
  group_by(ID, numofRooms) %>% 
  summarise(roomIDs = paste(roomIDs, collapse= '|'), numofbeds = sum(numofBeds))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups: ID [?]
#       ID numofRooms roomIDs                 numofbeds
#    <int>      <int> <chr>                       <int>
#1 1160545          1 1202544                        10
#2 1160546          2 1202547|1202563                 5
#3 1160547          2 1202562|1202564                 9
#4 1160548          1 1202565                         4
#5 1160549          1 1202566                         7
#6 1160550          3 1203751|1203752|1203753         6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method using `fuzzyjoin` package

```
fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(bookings, rooms, by=c("roomIDs"="roomID"))[,
    sum(numofBeds), by=names(bookings)]
```

data:

```
bookings  <- fread("ID   numofRooms                   roomIDs
1160545            1                   1202544
1160546            2           1202547|1202563
1160547            2           1202562|1202564
1160548            1                   1202565
1160549            1                   1202566
1160550            3   1203751|1203752|1203753")

rooms  <- fread("roomID   numofBeds
1202544          10
1202547           2
1202563           3
1202562           5
1202564           4
1202565           4
1202566           7
1203751           1
1203752           2
1203753           3", colClasses=c("character", "integer"))
```